# subversion: how to manage tweaked files

Tags: svn

Our group is considering moving to SVN.  But, I can't seem to find a way to do the following:

I need to make minor tweaks locally to about 20 files in the repository w/o having SVN consider them "changed" and included in the commit.  (Changes like communication time-outs and logging levels.)

Ideally I would want to merge the tweaked files to newer versions in the repository.  (Keeping the tweaked local file up-to-date with committed changes form other users.)

I can't imagine we're unique in wanting/needing this.

Are there best practices around this type of use case?

One thing I'm considering is putting all the tweaked files into a branched "tweaked" working copy.

Then merging my tweaked files into my "official" working copy.

Then using a script, which compares the "tweaked" and "official" working copies, to update my ignore list.  The script would also un-ignore and alert me to any files that had tweaks *and* other changes that, presumably, needed to be committed to the repository.

This seems kinda hacky and I can't imagine there's not a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have files that are in the repository, but you don't want to change, you're going to end up changing those files. It doesn't matter what version control system you're using. Someone is going to accidentally change those files.

There are a couple of things that can help:

1. I have a [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) that can prevent accidental changing of particular files. You say they're read only, and if someone tries to commit changes to them, the commit will be rejected.
2. Change lists can also be used. You can create a change list of files you do want to modify, and then just work with the changelist. Of course, accidental changes could happen (see pre-commit hook in point #1).
3. One thing to consider is changing the way you work. What if these *tweak files* had replaceable parameters. Then use your build system to tweak these files. I use Ant and setup a `build.template.properties` file that allows people to tweak the build. This file is checked in, but developers are suppose to copy it to `build.properties` and tweak it the way they want. I use `svn:ignore` and my pre-commit hook to make sure no one checks in an actual `build.properties` file.
4. Branching is cheap and easy to do in Subversion. Put the files on a branch and make the changes there. You can keep the branch up to date by periodically merging your original branch back to this branch. Since version 1.5, Subversion has an excellent merge tracking method that prevents duplicate merging.

Comment: For p.1 - these files also can be locked by special "locker" user - that even the real author could not change locked

Comment: 1. The pre-commit hook looks very powerful.  I can imagine us using it for a lot of things.  But, it doesn't look like it can easily be customized by an individual user to do something very user-specific.  <br/> 2. This might be the way to go assuming I can automatically create a change list and add all my tweaked files.  <br/>  3. I reviewed my tweaks and quite a few of them can be customized as you suggest.  However, some are so me-specific I won't be able to do that.  <br/>  4. Great.  I was sure hoping something like this would work!  <br/>  Thx!

Comment: Just to follow up...  Our group has finally moved to SVN and the change lists are working great for our needs.  One problem we're seeing is that the Eclipse plugins' "change sets" are not "real" SVN change lists. :^(

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what language you're using can you not load these tweaks from a single file that defines the values, and have a set of defaults that are committed to source control and allow each developer to create their own 'tweaks' file which is ignored?

This way the version in source is consistent and stable, with well reasoned sensible default values, however developers can tweak to their hearts content on their local copy.

Sounds less like a version control issue and more like a 'how are we getting the values to override the tweakable settings' issue.

Comment: I agree with the answer for the specific case of logging and timeout configuration. However, during debug and development I often have a need to make other experimental or investigatory changes. If so, I do a separate check-out after I know the changes I really want to make, and make those changes in a clean, recently checked-out copy. Working that way also reduces the risk of having to resolve conflicting changes in a team project.

Comment: Yeah I used to work that way too, now with git I just create a branch ;)

Comment: I agree with Michael about making the time-outs and log-levels configurable.  This will reduce the number of tweaked files for me.  But, there are still quite a few tweaks that are just for me.

Answer (score 0):

Side note: if

> I need to make minor tweaks locally to about 20 files in the repository w/o having SVN consider them "changed" and included in the commit.

is rather common requirement in your workflow, then you can think about using not Subversion, but, f.e, Mercurial with MQ+mqcollab extensions, or -X options in hg commit

Comment: Sadly, we have 2 options.  Internal tool or SVN.  I <3 mega-corps!

Answer (score 0):

Just don't commit the file that contains the settings.  Commit a file that is the "to be configured template" for the settings.  Then (if you're friendly) drop a "readme.txt" file explaining to copy the template file, open it in an editor, and set the appropriate values as the file describes in it's comments.

You are not unique in needing per-installation "tweaks", but why would you commit them in the first place.  Source code control is not "system backup", it's source code control.

PS.  If you really need to configure 20 different files as above, consider improving the centralization of your configuration control.

Comment: I will be able to reduce the number of tweaked files by doing as you suggest.  Not all of them though.  Also, would not be committing the tweaks.  Would need to revert the tweaks if making production changes.

Comment: Source code isn't a replacement for backups.  If this system needs to be restored, install a backup client and configure a backup system.  There might be more than just the 20 files you know about that were "tweaked" on a system.  Per-system changes are never part of the source code, but committing their templates makes sense.  over reliance on source code control to do _more than it was designed to do_ like backups will only distribute you (should be private) configuration to every development box, which might eventually be a major security hazard.